# Shutting down Windows Update service …

Tags: windows

After patching a Windows Server 2008r2 it just waits at the shutdown, saying:

```
Shutting down Windows Update service …
```

What should we do? Force the shutdown? It shows this for an hour now. Running on VMware.

UPDATE: text changed to: "Preparing to configure Windows, Do not turn off your computer" - maybe it is just too slow :)

Comment: How long was it before it changed to "Preparing..."?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We checked it on Monday again, it just took many-many hours to finish...

It is ok now :)